# Unity Sprite Sheet jagged on Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

I am using 2D sprite sheet to show an animation. It's working correct in editor and many Android devices except a specific Android (Nexus 5, Android 6) where the images looks jagged.

The sprite sheet size is *3115 x 4361*. Here are the sprite settings:

[image]

I tried **`Filter Mode`** to ***Point*** as well but the result is the same.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]  [image]

What could be the reason? It only happens on Nexus 5 (tested on more than 10 physical Android devices and Unity Editor).

Comment: for me it looks jagged (not blury) check this out:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/822051/jagged-pixelated-edges-on-all-sprites.html

Comment: I have already tried the suggestions in the link but I have the same result. Indeed jagged its better description of the problem, I will update the description of the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turning on *`Generate Mip Maps`* for the specific sprite solved the problem.